# Create query displaying sum and count and totals

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a timesheet where every entry has a Category, and total number of hours spend on that task. It looks like this...

[image]

How can i create a query/summary on another sheet in my excel document that creates a summary showing the total number of hours contributed to each Category, and the total cost for each category. It would be good for this query/summary to be dynamic so if i add a entry on the timesheet this summary reflects that, such as new category names.

Here is link to my sample excel doc > https://www.dropbox.com/s/75mtrec7tznx5nn/SampleTimesheet.xlsx?dl=0

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a pivot table will be useful here. There are lots of tutorials online to get you started. If you give that a go and still can't get it to work, come back and show us what you have done. I am sure we can help you out from there!

Comment: That was why i posted here. I tried doing, query, summary and some tables but didn't understand why everything just gave errors

Comment: But did you try Insert > PivotTable? PivotTables and Tables are two entirely different things